# Passing nested lists as tensors in tensor flow , where the inner lists have variable lengths

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, nested-lists

I have a list of lists which I want to convert to a tensor and use that in my program. The tricky part being, the inner lists can have variable size. For instance consider the following list- 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [ [2, 3], [4, 6] ], [[0], [1] ]] .
So is there a way I can represent this as a tensor and use it in my program(without padding zeros and making lists of same size)? Also I want to pass this as a placeholder.

Comment: you could pass a single string tensor with one element which has value "[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [ [2, 3], [4, 6] ], [[0], [1] ]]"